# Search in a list and return those items which contain a particular search phrase using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class WebItem :

```
class WebItem
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

User enters some search phrase and the program should find all items, where all terms from search phrase exist. E.x. user enters phrase: "some text". The program should find items, where

- (name contains "some" and description contains "text") or
- (name contains "text" and description contains "some") or
- (name contains "some" and keywords contains "text")  or
- (name contains "text" and keywords contains "some")  or
- (description contains "some" and keywords contains "text")  or
- (description contains "text" and keywords contains "some")  or
- (name contains "text" and name contains "some")  or
- (description contains "text" and description contains "some")  or
- (keywords contains "text" and keywords contains "some")

User can enter different length phrases. How to do that?

Comment: what have you tried? simple answers might involve "split on space, and for each term apply a or'd 'contains' check on each property" - however, I'm wondering if using a dedicated search tool such as Lucene or Elastic might pay dividends long term

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not going to give you a complete solution, but it sounds like you need to:

- Break up the user's input into words
- Check whether *all* the words are contained in the item in some form or other. The LINQ [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method will help you here. You only need to work out how to check where a *single* word appears in an item, then use `All` to apply that to all the search terms in a given query.

You may well want to change the structure of your `WebItem` though. If each of those properties can have multiple words in, you probably want to split those up... otherwise it's going to be tricky in terms of matching. For example, if the user types "am" as the search term, presumably you don't want it to match something with a description of "name", but you *do* want it to match something with a description of "I am here". Then you've got the problem of stemming, etc...

(As an aside, if you're splitting the terms you could match on anyway, you could create a single `HashSet<string>` for each `WebItem`, just for the purposes of matching.)

Marc's point about using a third-party API which is *designed* for this sort of thing is a good one, mind you.

Comment: you have so many points and badges that they are now being clipped!

Comment: @RichardSchneider change the zoom in your browser to 100% (it clips at 90%)

Comment: yes, maybe lucene.net or any other full text search engine may help, but lucene.net didn't fit this requirement due to incorrect configuration maybe. So it woild be excellent, if somebody could describe to configure lucene for mentioned search requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 var lst = new List<WebItem>();
        string searchString = "your text";
        string[] searchArr = searchString.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
        lst.Where((l) => searchArr.Count((s) => l.Name.Contains(s)) > 0
                         || searchArr.Count((s) => l.Keywords.Contains(s)) > 0
                         || searchArr.Count((s) => l.Description.Contains(s)) > 0);
```

Comment: If I search `"some text"` and an item has `Name = "some"` and `Description = "other"`, I would still get a hit with this. That item should not be returned according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Marc.

The solution is quite simple.

```
 //term - search phrase
 var terms = term.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 //searching list.
 var searchList = some_data_list_from_somethere_where_we_are_searching.AsEnumerable();

 foreach (var item in terms)
 {
     searchList = searchList.Where(q => q.Name.Contains(item) || 
                                        q.Keywords.Contains(item) || 
                                        q.Description.Contains(item));
 }
```

Comment: If I search `"some text"` and an item has `Name = "some"` and `Description = "other"`, I would still get a hit with this. That item should not be returned according to the question.